# Rails Routing with Optional Params on Root URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I am working on an app that allows for a user to go to the root url like so:
`http://localhost:3000/param_here`

My Routes are setup like the following:

```
match '/:test' => redirect { |params| "/?id=#{params[:test]}" }
```

The problem with this is that my other routes are being picked up and being redirected as well.

Full Route.rb

```
Myapp::Application.routes.draw do
  match '/:test' => redirect { |params| "/?id=#{params[:test]}" }
  match '/aboutus', to: 'pages#aboutus', as: "about_us"

  # Set the Home Page to a static page  
  root :to => 'pages#home'
end
```

So if a user goes to `/aboutus`, the redirect picks it up and assumes it should be set as the `id`. I still would like to use regular routes with also achieving this redirect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried moving the /aboutus route rule above the

```
  match '/:test' => redirect { |params| "/?id=#{params[:test]}" }
```

rule in your routes file?

Routes flow from the top down so if you move your /about us route above the route with the optional params it should dispatch your request to the first matching route, in this case the /aboutus route

Comment: Thanks! That worked like a charm! Can't accept the answer yet, but I will soon

Answer (score 1):

```
match '/:test' => redirect { |params| "/?id=#{params[:test]}" }, :defaults => { :id => '#{params[:test]}' }
```